# Lightbox Working Fine but Not Showing Scrollbar

Tags: lightbox2

I am using `lightbox2` but it hides my page scrollbar while opening, after closing scrollbar it stays hide.
I have checked css, if there is some issue with my blog, please let me know.

I have tried all browsers but same is happening on all browsers.

[Link to my page which have problem , you may check this...2](http://beautiesfromworld.blogspot.in/2013/03/amazing-aquarium.html)

Please help me out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your css.. 
whenever you are clicking on the image class named CSS_LIGHTBOX_FIXED_FRAME has been added to html tag and that class has the following css

```
html.CSS_LIGHTBOX_FIXED_FRAME {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden !important;
width: 100%;
}
```

remove the overflow:hidden part from above and you will have your scrollbar back

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
overflow hidden will hide the scrollbar na,
so i tried auto, and wow it's worked, btw thank you so much for taking me near to answer!!!!!
        Thanks ! overflow:auto; worked ! ;)

Comment: I have understand the main problem, my blogger's default lighbox is there showing up and adding class on opening,
Show i just disabled and got scroll works !